# best way to implement keyboard shortcuts in user control xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, user-controls, keyboard-shortcuts

I've an existing user control containing multiple child controls. i need to implement key board shortcuts here. creating a keyUp or KeyDown event does't help since hitting ctrl+S would make my browser save the page instead of hitting that event. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you already read through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189015%28VS.95%29.aspx)?

Comment: okay i solved this by creating two events for the parent control one which brought focus to the parent and second a keydown event. to bring focus to parent control i used MouseEnter event.